# How to add auto id to django model form

Tags: django, forms

My django model by default has an auto generated id field as primary key which is named 'id' by default on my db.

As such my model has a lot of other fields that I am selectively displaying using a Django model form. While doing so I specify 'id' for this auto generated id field but my form does not display or generate this field on HTML at all even though it seems to recognize this as a valid field.

I have also checked by doing an '**all**' for fields but this is also not bringing in that specific field. The funny thing is django does seem to recognize this field as 'id' because if I change it to 'Id' or anything else random it immediately gives me an error for example "Unknown field(s) (Id) specified for....." on my forms.py

This 'id' is important as I am using it to link and retrieve related objects using Ajax on client side. If this does not work then I will be forced to use another field as primary key. Any suggestions?

Comment: The id field is not supposed to be displayed in forms because it is an auto increment field, hence cannot be edited by the user.

Comment: If you need to retrieve related objects using ajax, just have the back-end print the object's id in a js variable. You don't need the id to be in a form for that. e.g. `<script> var myvar = {{ myobject.id }}; </script>`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a workaround as suggested by 'mastazi' for passing this id as a hidden field.

All I did is access this hidden field and generate it as an html element. Since I am using crispy_forms layout I was able to use an HTML element under Layout.

```
form_id= self.instance.id
id_hidden = '<input type="hidden" id="form_id" value=' + str(form_id)  +' />'
```

I am not sure if this is a perfect solution but it works.